# ActionMailer.net mvc4 simple webapp email sender

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
namespace ActionMailSample.Controllers
{
    public class MailController : MailerBase
    {
        //
        // GET: /Mail/

        public EmailResult SampleEmail()
        {
                From = "ExampleEmail@this.com";
                To.Add("ExampleEmail@there.com");
                Subject = "tha pikseis kolopsaro";
                return Email();<---ERROR no overload for method Email takes 0 arguments.

        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must enter the same name of the EmailResult and the viewmodel that came from the view where is the form to send.

> ```
> public class MailController : MailerBase
> {
>
>     public EmailResult SampleEmail(mail_ViewModel model)
>     {
>
>         To.Add("destination@email.com");
>         From = "from@email.com";
>         Subject = "Subject of Email";
>         return Email("SampleEmail", model);
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```

Dont forget when you create the view, append .txt or .html to Plain or Html email.
The name of this view in plain text will be SampleEmail.txt that will become the filename SampleEmail.txt.cshtml

In the view (SampleEmail.txt.cshtml) you can put something like this:

> @model TEST.Models.mail_ViewModel
>
> @{
>       Layout = null;
>   }
>
> Contact from Website
>
> Name: @Html.Raw(Model.Nome)
>   Email: @Html.Raw(Model.Email)
>   Subject: @Html.Raw(Model.Subject)
>   Message: @Html.Raw(Model.Message)

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Email()` expects one or more parameters. Consult the documentation for the `Email()` function to see what is expected and supply this information.